# XAMPP gives Forbidden 403 for everything but phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, xampp, local, vhosts

Long story short: I installed Windows 7 on my laptop everything is fine with OS. I installed latest xampp. What i did next via help of google and stackoverflow:

system32/drivers/etc/hosts

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1   local.projects
```

httpd-xampp.conf (allow from all is commented couse it totally had no effect at all).

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Deny from all
        Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
        fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
        fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16
    #Allow from all
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

And the main couse for the 403 being retrieved everywhere is *i think* THIS in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/Web-Pages"
    ServerName local.projects
    ServerAlias local.projects
    ErrorLog "logs/local.projects.log"
    CustomLog "logs/local.projects.log" combined
    <directory "D:/Web-Pages">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If there is anyhow you can point me to the right direction i would be very glad!
More info:

When i type in addressbar this "local.projects" or this "localhost" I get 403 like that:

---

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6

---

Okay, but when i access phpmyadmin at "localhost/phpmyadmin" everything works fine. When i add pressmission to the folders via Windows- nothing changes. Suggest any ideas how to get rid of these 403's please?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any pages in D:/Web-Pages directory? If this directory has no index page then it will show you 403 error.

If you have any page like, index.htm then try to browse `http://localhost/index.htm`.

Comment: I dont have index.php in D:\Web-Pages but i have index in c:\xampp\htdocs\ that is also giving me 403 so that means, that the problem aint cause of the missing index :( Im trying it all over and over again and it feels like im running in circles :((

Comment: can you try below in httpd-xampp.conf file.  
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Deny from all
        Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
 Allow from all
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>

Comment: Tried it, same result and i checked my error.log for apache it says: [Thu Jan 30 17:13:00.016241 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 3892:tid 1648] [client 127.0.0.1:49435] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: D:/Web-Pages/ I have all red pressmissions set in vhosts nothing is blocking it. i checked my Command prompt for wmic logicaldisk list it says that D: drive exists! ... And apache cant access it.